# How to persist checkbox selection with page refresh?

Tags: javascript, java, html, checkbox, thymeleaf

I'm working on a shopping list web app in Eclipse using Java, Thymeleaf, Spring, HTML and some CSS.  I used HTML to code a checkbox list into the app so when I am done with a certain list I can click the checkbox and it puts a line through the text.  However, when I refresh the page the checkbox doesn't stay checked.  I'd like to be able to keep the box checked with a page refresh.  I've tried various different bits of code from other Stack Overflow questions like coding Javascript into the HTML page, but nothing seems to work so far.  Here's my HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
 xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
 layout:decorator="layouts/basic">
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/templates.css/main.css}" />
<head>
<title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<style>
table, th, td {
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 padding: 15px;
}

.strikethrough:checked+.strikeThis {
 text-decoration: line-through
} 


</style>

</head>
<body layout:fragment="content">
 <div class="row">
  <h1>Shopping Lists</h1>
  <!-- a simple button for later to add shopping lists -->
  <a href="/" th:href="@{|/ListsofLists/add|}"><input type="button"
   value="Add list" /></a>
  <table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>&nbsp;</th>
     <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="list">
    <tr th:each="list : ${lists}">

     <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" class="strikethrough"
      value="1" /> <label for="check" class="strikeThis"
      th:text="${list.name}"> Name </label></td>
     <!--  <td th:text="${list.name}"></td> -->
     <td><a href="/" th:href="@{|/ListsofLists/${list.id}|}">Show</a></td>
     <td><form method="POST">
       <input type="hidden" name="listId" th:value="${list.id}" />
       <button type="submit">Delete</button>
      </form></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I will try to answer as many questions as possible in order to figure out this question.  Apologies if it's something rather simple, I am new to coding and still learning.

Comment: There are so many ways to do that an easy one could be cookies

Comment: You can use session attribute in your controller class

Answer (score 1):

You need to save your checkbox state to local storage. So the browser can check the boolean value true or false of your checkbox when it loaded / refresh.

Here's the tutorial for storing checkbox state on local storage :
https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-persist-checkbox-checked-state-after-page-reload/

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify a way to store that the checkbox has been selected. Typically solutions involve localstorage/cookies, sessions, or through a database.

When the box is checked, store it somewhere. Similarly, if it's unchecked you need to store that preference as well. And then with each page load, you need to do a check to see if there is a saved preference or you should just go to the default.

There are benefits to each storage option. [Local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) & [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) are very easy to implement. But they're located on the client's machine, thus they're volatile. If it's important information, don't rely solely on this method. Session Storage ([php](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) or [HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)) will last for the duration of the browser session. This is helpful if you don't need the data to persist as a permanent selection. If you need it to be permanent, you need to save things out to a database.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.

One of the more popular methods is to use JavaScript [`cookies`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie). In this method you would set a cookie like `checkbox=true` and grab that value on page refresh.

Another method is to set a [`location hash`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) parameter in JavaScript, likewise reading this parameter on page load.

Lastly, you could also use HTML5 [`LocalStorage`](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

*These are all the client-side methods for doing this. You can always do this on server-side using a HTML parsing script written in PHP or your language of choice.*

As I mentioned on another SO question recently, running a page refresh clears out all of the values set before in both JavaScript and HTML forms. Everything goes. *For future people who read this, please do not use page refresh in JavaScript code. It makes many people very angry, and causes them to pull out their hair uncontrollably.*

Answer (score 0):

You could use local storage to store user's checkbox selection and on page refresh you can retrieve the checkbox selection from local storage and set the checkbox selection.

Simple examples of using local storage is:

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

You can view more details about local storage on w3schools here(http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Relevant to your case you can use jQuery and local storage using this guide(https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-persist-checkbox-checked-state-after-page-reload/) to remember user's selection when a checkbox is clicked and retrieve them when page refreshes.